# How can I use getResources() in SpannableString?

Tags: android, spannablestring

I am creating a small Android app. I would like to display a clickable text in a textview. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   // SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world));
   SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello world!");

    final ClickableSpan clickableSpan111 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ";)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan111, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(TextUtils.concat("my text ", ss));
        textView.setMovementMethod(new LinkMovementMethod());
    }

}
```

It works normally, but if I change code from

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello world!");
```

to

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world));
```

application don't work.
How can I use getResources() in SpannableString?

Comment: I try to enter non-breaking space U+00A0, &nbsp to clickablespan

Comment: I try make clickable non-breaking space in string <string name="my string">Hello\u00A0world"</string>

Comment: in your code the clickable area is Hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xml resources file you can add the unicode for the non-breaking space it should works like this `\u00A0` 
try to add it in ur string file

According to [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)

then you can add this

```
youspannable.setSpan(clickableSpan, the starting index for nonbreaking space, the last index, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
then
textView.setText(youspannable);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

this should be inside on create because you are calling getResources() too early in the activity lifecycle.

so you code should be like this

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world));

    final ClickableSpan clickableSpan111 = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ";)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan111, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(TextUtils.concat("my text ", ss));
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

}
```

Comment: I am trying to do it, but code don't work if I use SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_gap_world));
where Sring.hello_gap_world is <string name=" hello_gap_world">Hello\u00A0world"</string>

Comment: I have stopped application if I use SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world)); instead of   SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello world!");
This is the first problem.
Non-breaking space is the second problem in my application.

Comment: do u mean the app crash ?

Comment: try to moveSpannableString ss = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world)); to inside of concrete

Comment: Yes, Now it work fine inside onCreate!!! But if I need to use SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world));  upper OnCreate in more complex caces?